# Suppress console output from React in Jest testing output but not in browser output

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, console, react.js

I have a React app that I am testing with the built-in jest testing tools. In the process of debugging, I sometimes send data to the console (e.g. `console.log`, `console.error`, etc.) from my code-under-test. This shows up both in the browser console as well as in the testing output in the terminal which is what I sometimes want.

However, sometimes I want to send such debugging messages to *either*:

1. the testing terminal *or*
2. the browser,

but *not both*.

I know how to do #1: just include the `console.log` in the jest test code rather than in the code-under-test. However, if I want to do #2, I'm not quite sure what to do.

I tried the following in the code-under-test:

```
if (!jest) {
  console.log('some browser-only output');
}
```

That does suppress the output in the test, which otherwise behaves normally, i.e. no error is thrown during testing. However, it does *not* output anything in the browser but instead throws an error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: jest is not defined"`, i.e. there is no `let jest = ...` or `const jest = ...` anywhere in the code.

I did come up with a solution:

```
try { jest; }
catch(e) {
    console.log('some browser-only output');
}
```

This gives me the desired results. However, the solution feels very hack-y: It requires throwing an error in order to work, which just "smells" wrong, even for a debugging tool.

So, is there a better way for me to check whether `jest` exists without throwing an error? Or another way to see if testing is underway, again without throwing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a way of checking for the `jest` global that won't throw an error:

```
if (typeof jest == 'undefined') {
  console.log('some browser-only output');
}
```

You can also take advantage of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    console.log('browser');
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test') {
    console.log('jest');
}
```

Comment: That difference that you point out between `!myVar` and `typeof myVar === 'undefined'` is not only applicable to this specific problem but also more generally as well, and a distinction I hadn't been previously been aware of. I'll probably use that elsewhere too. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps someone else:
`jest --silent`

http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#silent

Answer (score 5):

You can use the setUpFiles option to configure files to be run before jest run tests. More info here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Then in your set up file, you can disable logging. For example, to disable console.log, you can do `console.log = function() {}`

Comment: Note that for React applications created with CRA, you should use `src/setupTests.js`. [More info](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#srcsetuptestsjs)